# Golang path to file inside docker container

Tags: docker, go

I have a `.pem` file which I can access with no problem using `filepath.Abs` when my application is not running inside docker. When the app is running inside docker, golang cant find the file anymore.

How can I access the file with golang running inside a docker container?

Thanks

Comment: What does your code look like? How are you getting the pem file into the Docker image? Is it where you expect it to be if you run a shell inside the container and inspect it manually?

Answer (score 4):

You should use volumes to share your pem file between your host and your container, something like :

```
docker run -v /path/to/my/file.pem:/app/file.pem <your_image>
```

The application inside the Docker container will then be able to access the file `file.pem` located in `/app/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

you should set the workdir in `Dockerfile`

```
RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/code
WORKDIR $GOPATH/code  /your-code-directory
```

Or for example write your Dockerfile like that example:

```
FROM golang:latest

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go build -o main .
RUN chmod a+x /docker_entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker_entrypoint.sh"]
```

In docker_entrypoint.sh you can prepare your code, copy or create files and start your project `exec run server.go`